# Ajax Gives Random Result while trying to bind table in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

> i am trying to populate html table from database c# and jquery AJax.But while i run it. it gives sometime success and some time Undefined And Sometime Blank Alert Box by while i pass same parameter every time.And When It Success It Bind Table But this table couln't hols on page it shows but disappear at once.
>   Here Is My Code:
>   **C# Code**

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static Report[] databind(string srh)
        {
            List<Report> list1 = new List<Report>();
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = SQLDatabaseManager.ExecuteDataTable("select *,convert(nvarchar,IssueDate,106) as Idate,convert(nvarchar,ValidDate,106) as Vdate,convert(nvarchar,NextAuditDate,106) as Ndate from [Staun_Icrtms].[tbl_Clients] where Org_name like '%" + srh + "%' order by Org_name desc ");
                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Report data1 = new Report();

                        data1.orgName = dr["org_name"].ToString();
                        list1.Add(data1);
                    }
                }
                return list1.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return list1.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Jquery Ajax**

```
function DataBind() {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "ClientReport.aspx/databind",
                data: "{srh:" + JSON.stringify($('#txtName').val()) + "}",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    if (data.d.length > 0) {
                        alert('Success')
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                            $('#tblClient').append('<tr><td>' + data.d[i].orgName + '<td><tr/>');
                        }                        
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr)
                {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
                })
        }
```

Comment: I promise to you create a class that contains some parameters as `data` , `message` , and etc. then return array of that. ex. `ResponseModel` class that contains `data` and `message`. when exception occurred set exception message to the `message` field and when data is ready put it to `data` field. at the client, you know every when that response is something like `ResponseModel` and you can handle that better.

Comment: that doesn't work remain same problem occured